# How to make piped lambda returning some value

Tags: f#, lambda, pipe

It's hard to explain, here is what I want:

```
let internal (=%=) (W : int, thriller : Dev -> unit -> bool) =
    let id = get W
    if id <> -1 then
        workbase.[id] |> thriller
```

It doesn't allow my thriller to return any type.

So I can do `W =%= fun w -> foo()` where `foo()` is `unit`

But how can I do `W =%= fun w -> foo()` where `foo()` is `unit -> T'` (some type) ?

*thank you*

just added final usage (because like it):

```
let CanRead     W dev v = W =%= fun w -> w.GetCanRead dev v
                        |> fun opt -> if opt.IsSome then opt.Value
                                      else false
```

after comment:

```
let CanRead     W dev v =   match W =%= fun w -> w.GetCanRead dev v with
                            | Some(t)   -> t
                            | None      -> false
```

Comment: On your usage, more idiomatic F# is to use `match opt with |Some(t) -> ... |None -> ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `else` branch is missing.

When you return `unit` in if/else expression, `if... then...` is a shortcut to `if... then... else ()`. So you can always return some type T in a complete if/else expression, for example, an option type as follows:

```
let internal (=%=) (W : int, thriller : Dev -> unit -> bool) =
    let id = get W
    if id <> -1 then
        Some (workbase.[id] |> thriller)
    else None
```

Comment: Thank you! Option is exactly what I need here.

Answer (score 2):

You must have an 'else' part in the if-then construction. It have to return a result in any case.

Comment: you don't 'need' an `else` - you only need it if your if statement doesn't return `unit`

Comment: @John : Your if _expression_. ;-]